# MVC4 Hide or disable field using controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im new to mvc4, nw i got an issue. 
In Controller i will check Which field should be hide or disable.
For normal c# i can use .visible to solve,

but MVC4 + razor, i Totally no idea
i do not want to add css class for every textbox,textarea like below

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "hide" })

1- Javascript

//construct hidden field in controller
Viewbag.hideField = "#message,blah,blah";

//hide with javascript in view
$(@Viewbag.hideField).hide();

This is all i can think of, any gorgeous way to achieve this...

These field are dynamic, it based on user role to determine its show or hide,
if i do this checking in view, it will be tedious job to do, 
so i thinking is there anyway i can do it programmatic in controller.

Comment: no need for the JS. Just have css rule for that class: `display: none;`

Comment: Thank Dmitry for try, but its not tat simple. These field are dynamic, it based on user role to determine its show or hide, if i do this checking in view, it will be tedious job to do, so i thinking is there anyway i can do it programmatic in controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper for that:

```
Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Message)
```

or apply a css rule to class hidden:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: those field are dynamic, which means, for some user its hide,some user its show, and i wan to use controller to control. so i do not need to add checking to every textfield in view

Comment: controller can only control values of the properties of the model. You'd need some sort of checking in the view

Comment: i guess so, coz i search for sometime d, i'm thinking override htmlhelper to do it. by before create textbox adding viewbag checking

Answer (score 0):

What's so bad about hard coding the data in the HTML and using javascript or css?  It's pretty much how the web works!

Here is another option: What about creating a list of elements in the controller and then using the list returned in the view?

You could then do like

var itemsToDisplay = new List()

```
if (User.Role == Admin)
{
var htmlHelper = HtmlHelper()
 itemsToDisplay.Add(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name).ToString());
}

return View("view",itemsToDisplay)
```

Comment: but it like not MVC, V is not longer a view, secondly i still hav to change the all view templatee